# Separating System.Out messages and Scanner (Java)

Tags: java, system.in

Is there a way, without using a gui package of any sort, to not have System.out inject itself into the middle of your prompt?

The scenario is a threaded program where you send and receive messages to a server.

While writing to the server, you get a message from the server.

"I'm writinMESSAGE FROM SERVERg a message"

So you basically end up seeing something like that in your console.

Is there a way to circumvent this problem and essentially separate the prompt from the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this to buffer output temporary:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PrintStream oldOut = System.out;
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(out));

    // System.in read code

    System.setOut(oldOut);
    System.out.println(out.toString());
```

Same for `System.err`

Comment: +1 If you add an `out.reset()` call too, the buffer becomes ready for reuse.

Comment: Perhaps I spoke too soon, my calls to system.out are in one thread and the system.in are in a different thread.  Not entirely sure where this would go, though I understand the idea.